# Installed C++ build tools via Visual Studio Installed, but pip install pycocotools still give me error

Tags: python-3.x, detectron, layout-parser

Installing pycotools via pip install gives the error
[error log of failing to install pycotools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQPct.png)

I have installed C++ build tools via Visual Studio Installed
[image of installed C++ build tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANAYv.png)

But, when I `pip install pycocotools`,
It still gives the error
[error log of failing to install pycotools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt2Ty.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not try for installing pycocotools(original) on Visual Studio.
if you want to do that, you must install clone of pycocotools from this: https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi

Answer (score 0):

Thx to MAHDI SOLTANI PAKDEL's solution,
I have found an alternative solution: installing `pycocotools` won't require C++ build tools.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pycocotools
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pycocotools
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pycocotools
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pycocotools
```